# 2D heatmap of frequency over magntiude from FFTs

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

How to create a 2D heat map (or similar) with frequency on the x-axis and the magnitude on the y-axis?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 1000
t = np.arange(0, 0.1, 1/fs)
N = len(t)
f_bin = fs / N
f = np.arange(0, fs, f_bin)
X = [np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 100 * t)), np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 200 * t)), np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 300 * t))]
M = np.absolute(X)

fig1, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax1.plot(f[:len(f)//2], M[0,:len(M[0][:])//2], "r+", label="100 Hz")
ax1.plot(f[:len(f)//2], M[1,:len(M[1][:])//2], "g*", label="200 Hz")
ax1.plot(f[:len(f)//2], M[2,:len(M[2][:])//2], "b.", label="300 Hz")
ax1.set_xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Magnitude")
ax1.set_title(f"DFT")
ax1.grid(True, which="both")
ax1.legend()
plt.show()
```

In general I search for a good way to visualize in a single picture the output of multiple (e.g., 1000 and not just three as in this example) FFTs (e.g., with `matplotlib.imshow()`?, `numpy.histogram2d()`?).

Comment: What's your question? You said you want a 2D heat map, but only mention the x- and y-axes; what dictates the color? Do you have 2D data for this?

Comment: Mhh, the more often a magnitude value occur at a certain frequency, the "hoter" the map at this point become? As mentioned in the end of this questions, I search for a let's call it "state-of-art" method to deal with a hugh amout of FFTs and visualize it. To e.g., find the ocurrency of dedicated frequencies or outliers (e.g., noise frequencies).

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you mean "multiple FFT spectra" and not just "one FFT spectrum with multiple spectral components"?

Comment: Multiple FFT spectra from my understanding: E.g., 1000 measurements (ADC sampling) each 1280 samples (N) and do for every measurement a FFT. In the example I have added 3 "measurements".

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you could use `GaussianProcessRegressor` (as well as `BayesianGaussianMixture`) to get heatmap-style representations of normality.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a task suitable for `sklearn`'s `GaussianProcessRegressor`. Data and code for the plots is at the end.

Original data:

[image]

After fitting a gaussian process, you can plot the mean prediction and a band showing what you think is the normal range:

[image]

Or equivalently a heatmap-style plot:

[image]

Another approach is to get a density plot of magnitude vs frequency using a `BayesianGaussianMixture`. If a new line falls in the darker (low density) region, you can flag it as an anomaly. Code for these figures is below.

Data with density estimate for anomaly detection:

[image]

---

Data and code for the plots.

Synthesise data:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 10_000
t = np.arange(0, 0.05, 1/fs)
N = len(t)
f_bin = fs / N
f = np.arange(0, fs, f_bin)
v = [np.sinc(2 * np.pi * f * t)**2*(np.random.rand(len(t))>0.5) for f in range(100, 110)]
X = [np.fft.fft(time) for time in v]
X_arr = np.stack(X, axis=0)
M = np.absolute(X_arr)

f_rpt = np.tile(f[:N//2].reshape(-1, 1), [len(v), 1])
M_flat = M[:, :N//2].reshape(-1, 1)
```

Code for fitting and plotting a gaussian process:

```py
#
#Fit gaussian process
#
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(n_restarts_optimizer=9)
gp.fit(f_rpt, M_flat)

#Plot mean prediction and an error band
mean_pred, std_pred = gp.predict(f[:N//2].reshape(-1, 1), return_std=True)
plt.plot(f[:N//2], M[:, :N//2].T)
plt.plot(f[:N//2].ravel(), mean_pred, 'r-', linewidth=7, label='mean prediction')
plt.fill_between(
    f[:N//2].ravel(),
    mean_pred - 4e5 * std_pred,
    mean_pred + 4e5 * std_pred,
    alpha=0.4,
    label='normality band'
)
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.ylabel('magnitude')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Data with band for identifying normal lines')
plt.show()

#Heatmap-style plot for gaussian process
import matplotlib
cmap = matplotlib.cm.plasma
stds = np.logspace(1, 6, 1000)
for std in stds:
    plt.plot(f[:N//2], mean_pred + std * std_pred, color=cmap(std / stds.max()), alpha=0.8)
    plt.plot(f[:N//2], mean_pred - std * std_pred, color=cmap(std / stds.max()), alpha=0.8)

plt.plot(f_rpt, M_flat, 'w.', markersize=2)
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.ylabel('magnitude')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Density measure overlaid with orginal data')
plt.show()
```

Code for fitting and plotting a bayesian mixture model:

```py
fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(f[:N//2], M[:, :N//2].T)
ax.set_xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
ax.set_ylabel("Magnitude")
ax.set_title("DFT")
plt.show()

#Fit clusterer to get density plot
from sklearn.mixture import BayesianGaussianMixture

f_and_M = np.concatenate([f_rpt, M_flat], axis=1)
bgm = BayesianGaussianMixture(n_components=20, random_state=0)
bgm.fit(f_and_M)

#Plotting code adapted from:
#   github.com/ageron/handson-ml3/blob/main/09_unsupervised_learning.ipynb
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
X = f_and_M
clusterer = bgm
resolution = 1000
mins = X.min(axis=0) - 0.1
maxs = X.max(axis=0) + 0.1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(mins[0], maxs[0], resolution),
                     np.linspace(mins[1], maxs[1], resolution))
Z = -clusterer.score_samples(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,
            norm=LogNorm(vmin=1.0, vmax=30.0),
            levels=np.logspace(0, 2, 12), cmap='plasma_r')
plt.contour(xx, yy, Z,
            norm=LogNorm(vmin=1.0, vmax=30.0),
            levels=np.logspace(0, 2, 12),
            linewidths=1, colors='k')

plt.plot(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], 'w.', markersize=2)
plt.xlabel("frequency")
plt.ylabel("magnitude")
plt.title('Density plot (white lines are the original data)')
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm quite "happy" with

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fs = 1000
t = np.arange(0, 0.1, 1/fs)
N = len(t)
f_bin = fs / N
f = np.arange(0, fs, f_bin)
X = [np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 100 * t)), np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 200 * t)), np.fft.fft(np.sin(2 * np.pi * 300 * t))]
M = np.absolute(X)

fig1, (ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax1.plot(f[:len(f)//2], M[0,:len(M[0][:])//2], "r+", label="100 Hz")
ax1.plot(f[:len(f)//2], M[1,:len(M[1][:])//2], "g*", label="200 Hz")
ax1.plot(f[:len(f)//2], M[2,:len(M[2][:])//2], "b.", label="300 Hz")
ax1.set_xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
ax1.set_ylabel("Magnitude")
ax1.set_title(f"DFT")
ax1.grid(True, which="both")
ax1.legend()
plt.show(block=False)

fig2, (ax1) = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(M[:,:len(M[0,:]) // 2], cmap='viridis', aspect=1)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Index")
plt.ylabel("# FFT")
plt.show()
```

[image]